# php - How can I miss out parameters when calling a function?

Tags: php, function, optional-parameters

I am making a PHP script.

My script has a function that looks something like this:

`function myFunction($param1 = "foo", $param2 = "bar") {}`

Let's say I want to specify a value for $param2, but want to skip $param1 as the default value is fine, how could I do something like this:

`myFunction(param2)`?

Tl;Dr: Can I skip certain parameters when calling a function?

Comment: No. Unfortunately, php doesn't allow this. If you want to specify a parameter on the right, you always have to specify the parameters on the left.

Comment: Oh man, that sucks. Oh well - thanks anyway!

Comment: kind of a way around this is to use an array  as the argument, then you can 'skip' array keys with out issue `function myFunction($param1 = array()) {}` `myFunction(array('a'=>7))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you using optional parameter you will have to put it at the end. There's no way to "skip" an argument other than to specify a default like false or null.

Comment: Ok, that's unfortunate :( 

Thanks though!